# Can I Sort the data in my table display in html based on the count that I have in my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So for example I have a table that is displayed like this.

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So this data is not save on my database, but I have save their actual count, so whenever I'm gonna edit they will just be rumble in my view, and my goal is to arrange them first based on their count.

```
var count = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

so with this array, assume that this is their arrangement. My question is how or is it possible to arrange them base on my count variable by using the ID column?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems you want to sort the table rows based on a specific column. Is there a specific event that should trigger this? What have you tried so far and what is not working? Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @Twisty, so assume that when the user click the ```Edit button``` that table data will already be there, but there will be a unique data that will be on the response which is their count or arrangement.

Comment: I am unable to assume anything. I do not see an "Edit" button in your example. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```js
const sort = (rows, sort) => sort.map(e => rows.find(({ id }) => id == e))
const getRowId = (row) => +jQuery(jQuery(row).find('td')[0]).text() // 0 is the first column
const getSortObj = (row) => ({ id: getRowId(row), row })

const setDirectionText = (directionSpan) => (direction) => directionSpan.text(direction)

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let sortByArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  let direction = "ASC"
  const directionSpan = setDirectionText($("#direction"))
  directionSpan(direction)

  $('#btn-sort').on('click', function() {
    const $rows = $('#table tbody tr')
    const sortedRows = sort($.map($rows, getSortObj), sortByArr).map(({ row }) => row)
    $('#table tbody').html(sortedRows)
    
    sortByArr = sortByArr.reverse()
    direction = direction === "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC"
    directionSpan(direction)
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<button id="btn-sort">SORT TABLE <span id="direction"></span></button>
<br />
<br />
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This snippet does a bit more than you asked for: it can sort in ascending and descending order - toggled after each sorting.